# Spark Streaming - Calling REST API vs Building Functionality Natively for Spark Streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

We have a specific functionality for managing timeseries data. The funtionality is already offered as REST API and runs on Cloudfoundry. We want to offer the support for ingesting timeseries data using Spark Streaming and kafka so that the solution is more scalable and robust. 
What are the disadvantages of calling the REST API from spark streaming intead building the functionality natively in spark.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that if your REST API can support the throughput from Spark Streaming, the REST API can support the throughput directly. In which case, you don't actually need Spark Streaming at all.  If what you need is a buffer for unexpected spikes, there are simpler ways to achieve that than Spark Streaming.

To address your question more directly, calling the REST API adds latency and an additional failure case to the Spark Streaming pipeline.  Implementing your logic in Spark Streaming directly adds code complexity and possible duplication. And both options add operational complexity.

Comment: Thanks ImDarrenG ...I totally agree to your inputs.